# How to get past Grafana open source million rows limit

Tags: grafana

Hi I have a table view in Grafana which I am using for querying database of MSSQL which has over 1.5 million rows and trying to export it as a csv in grafana. I hit a roadblock where I couldn't retrieve rows beyond 1 million in grafana: "query row limit exceeded, limit 1000000". Is there any way out of this? I tried searching if Grafana enterprise would be able to help us out here but was unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, edit that constant in the source code and build own Grafana with own limit.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/d4e4cb4c7179fd73a7f575d198dfed2ad9581a1a/pkg/tsdb/sqleng/sql_engine.go#L128

Anyway, it looks like you are using wrong tool for CSV export. Grafana is not the best tool for MSSQL mass CSV export. I would use `SQL Server Management Studio` for this type of CSV export.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Grafana 8.2.0, a row_limit configuration variable was added so that you can change this limit - it still defaults to 1000000, but you can now increase or lower the limit.

The change was made mainly so you can lower it and avoid other problems, but you could also increase it - though depending on your usage, you might hit other limitations.

Search for `row_limit` on this page for the documentation of this configuration value:

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana

And refer to this now closed issue:

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/38975